# Strange block/extends interaction going on in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

so in my home page I extend from 2 things, based on whether or not the user is signed in or not. Then, if they have TRIED to sign in, and failed, i want the inputs to be red:

```
{% extends extendVar %} #in this case, extendvar=notLoggedIn.html
    {% block signIn %}
        {% if failure %}
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

notLoggedIn.html then includes from a header page:

```
<div class="container" style="">
    {% include 'header.html' %}
</div>
```

And this has a block tag:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="{% static 'images/Logo.png' %}" style="height:auto; max-width:470px; margin-top:-22px; margin-bottom:-30px; padding-right:10px;">
      </a>
  </ul>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'signIn' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
          {% block signIn %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn" href="" role="button" style="">Sign in </button>
          {% endblock %}
          </form>
      </div>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

Project name</h3> -->

my only problem is that because i am including header in NotLoggedIn, and then extending that, it doesnt preserve the block tags, and so the signIn blocks are not working. If instead of doing include header, i merely hard-code it, the blocks work perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the django documentation, when you use "include", blocks in the included template are evaluated first, and then substituted in. So in your template, you can't override a block of the included template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Instead of using a block, what if you pass variables down to the include block, to get it to render how you want? For example:

Your template:

```
{% include 'header.html' with failure=failure %}
```

header.html:

```
<div class="form-group {% if failure %}has-error{% endif %}">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group {% if failure %}has-error{% endif %}">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
</div>
```